How to map enums with Mapster
I've recently just started using Mapster and I'm trying to do a mapping enum values to an object. I tried the simple way to map using .Map() but it doesn't work. Here's are the objects
class DropdownDto<T>
{
   public T Id {get; set;}
   public string StringValue {get; set;}
}

enum WasteClassificationEnum 
{
   [Display(Name = "Biodegradable Waste Material")
   Biodegradable = 1,
   [Display(Name = "Recyclables")
   Recyclable = 2,
   [Display(Name = "Residual Waste Material")
   Residual = 3,
   [Display(Name = "Uncategorized")
   Special = 4
}

class WasteMaterialDto
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set:}
   // ... some more attributes here
}


I wanted to map WasteMaterialDto's Id and Name to the WasteClassificationEnum then pass it to the DropdownDto.
I tried doing something like this:
TypeAdapterConfig(WasteMaterialDto, DropdownDto<WasteClassificationEnum>>.NewConfig()
  .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
  .Map(dest => dest.StringValue, src => src.Name);

But this produces a null value. Is this possible? Mapster is a whole new concept for me and I can only find the simplest of samples on the internet.
